# Alternative ways to pass model from one controller action to another in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model, controller

I have about 6-7 different actions within the same controller that get hit on each view loading. How I'm doing this now is like so:

`person_id` is passed into the URL.

## persons_controller

```
person_id = params[:person_id]
people = PersonSearch.where(:person_id => person_id)
@response_people = people.map do |p|
  {
      :name => p.name,
      :age => p.age
  }
```

The above code snippet is written in 6-7 actions within my controller, which equates to 6-7 views that I need to display `name` and `age` on.

How could I look this person up by ID in my first view then track that specific `person` model through each action without having to look him up and use a `.map` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like this

```
def set_person
     person_id = params[:person_id]
     people = PersonSearch.where(:person_id => person_id)
     @response_people = people.map do |p|
     {
           :name => p.name,
           :age => p.age
     }
end
```

And then at the top of your controller add this but replace :show and :edit with the controller actions you want to set person on.

```
before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit]
```

This will run the set_person function prior to each action you specify given you access to `@response_people` in your views.